# View android files on Mac cordova.file.dataDirectory appears empty

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I have a Cordova app that uses the file plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.3.0 "File Transfer"
```

I download some images from the web (my own server/images) to this loaction with the file transfer plugin

```
var imagePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "images/" + subdir + "/" + imagefile;
```

All works well. On iOS using iExplorer I can see my files but with Android, using Android File Transfer (https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) I can see the directories upto "files" but no more - it seems empty after that.

[image]

This happens with Android 4.2 and 4.4 both in debug mode and MTP enabled. I looked in the other directories such as DCIM and can't see my files. Also used the file browser builtin app and same issue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there was no response to my question I'll post a solution I found.

Firstly, it seems I cannot see my files because my device is not rooted (sorry, lost link to where I read this). Did not try rooting as found an alternative:

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as com.mycompany.myapp
$ cd files
$ ls
```

Ref : http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/the-right-location-for-your-cordova-app-files